# Ruby =~ vs === Operators

Tags: ruby, regex, operator-overloading

I had mostly been using `===` for matching values to patterns in Ruby. Recently, I discovered that the language also supports the `=~` operator for regular expressions.

The [Ruby Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html) defines `===` as "case equality" and `=~` as "pattern match".

> Case Equality – For class Object, effectively the same as calling #==, but typically overridden by descendants to provide meaningful semantics in case statements.
>
> Pattern Match—Overridden by descendants (notably Regexp and String) to provide meaningful pattern-match semantics.

By experimentation, I find that `===` works for regular expressions, class names, literal values, and even ranges, while `=~` only seems to return useful values for regular expressions. My question is: why would I ever use `=~`? It seems like `===` supports everything `=~` does and then some. Is there something I'm missing here that `=~` is intended to do differently?

Comment: `regexp =~ str` and `regexp === str` return quite different results on my system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, `=~` is symmetric:

```
'string' =~ /regex/
```

And

```
/regex/ =~ 'string'
```

Both work.

Secondly as you noted, `===` works with other classes. If you want to match strings, you should be using the operator for... matching. It is called case operator for a reason - `case` uses it internally.

```
case foo
when bar then x
when baz then y
else z
end
```

Is the same as:

```
if bar === foo
  x
elsif baz === foo
  y
else
  z
end
```

Explicitly using `===` is considered [unidiomatic](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#no-case-equality).

Comment: From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E): *"Note: `str =~ regexp` is not the same as `regexp =~ str`. Strings captured from named capture groups are assigned to local variables only in the second case."*

Comment: @Stefan, interesting. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: Must be some internal limitation. According to [`Regexp#=~`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) the implicit variable assignment is handled by the Ruby parser.

Answer (score 4):

```
str = "Something is amiss."
r = /me/

r === str #=> true
str =~ r  #=> 2
```

What if you want to know if there's a match and if so, where it begins?